# INSERT or UPDATE if condition over two columns (regardless of order) is met

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

I want to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (term1, term2, number) values ('A','B',10);
```

however if values A and B are already present in `table1` **regardless** of their order, ie. the predicate

```
(term1='A' && term2='B') OR (`term1='B' && term2='A')
```

holds true, then I just want to update column number. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by _however if term1 and term2 have occurred in a row "REGARDLESS" of their order_?

Comment: @okiharaherbst what I'm trying to say is, if term1= "a" and term2="b", I don't want to add a new row that is term1="b" and term2="a", instead I want to update the number.

Comment: @nafas so you want to update number column alone by value 10 right?

Comment: You want to update all rows that match?

Comment: if they match then I just want to update the number if they don't match I want to insert a new row basically.

Comment: I understand, is it possible that many rows might match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (perhaps *the*) ***clean way*** to handle this situation is to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, [read the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL
>   performs an UPDATE of the old row

The important part is *would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index*. Therefore you need to create an **multicolumn unique index**.

Now I'm not sure if you can manage the order that way, therefore I'd create an extra field with the concatenation of the sorted values of your fields, and have that field uniquely indexed.

**EDIT**: Instead of storing the concatenation your fields, you could also just store the hash and index it.

Comment: You could concatenate the sorted list of fields.

Comment: @copper.hat Actually, sure, that's indeed sufficient, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @okiharaherbst,

This is what I did: I added new column "uniqueKey" as primary key and insert goes as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table1(term1,term2,num,uniquekey) VALUES ( "a","b",10, 
concat(greatest(term1,term2),least(term1,term2))) on duplicate key update num=10;
```

Comment: that'll do the job. shine on!